# how to Find and count duplicate numbers in a string array in vb.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

how to count the duplicate numbers exist in a string or integer array in vb.net?

```
Dim a as string = "3,2,3"
```

> from the above "a" variable i want a count of "3" as 2 (i mean 3 exist 2 times) and "2" as "1". So how do i make it in vb.net?????

Actually i will get the above string "a" from the sql database. so i dont know which numbers are there. That's why i am asking here.

Comment: as shown, `a` is a string, not a string array

Comment: yeah bro it is a string. but is there any way to find its count??? @Plutonix

Comment: Are you looking for shortest code on this one too :-)

Comment: @Shar1er80 definitely.... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already got some good answers to choose from, but I thought you'd be interested in a one liner solution.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim str() As String = "1,2,1,2,3,1,0,1,4".Split(","c)
        str.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(Sub(digit) Console.WriteLine("{0} exists {1}", digit, str.Count(Function(s) s = digit)))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Explanation as to what's happening:

- `str.`[Distinct()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) - Returns an `IEnumerable` object of all unique items in the array
- `.`[ToList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) - Turns the `IEnumerable` object into a `List<T>`
- `.`[ForEach()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) - Iterates through the `List<T>`

  - `Sub(digit)` - Defines an [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate to perform on each element.  Each element is named digit during each iteration.
  - You should know what `Console.WriteLine()` is doing
  - `str.`[Count()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535181(v=vs.100).aspx) - Will count each occurrence a digit that satisfies a condition

    - `Function(s) s = digit` - Defines a [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549151(v=vs.100).aspx) delegate that will count each occurrence of digits in the array.  Each element, in `str()`, during the Count iterations are stored in the variable `s` and if it matches the digit variable from `Sub(digit)` it will be counted

Results:

```
1 exists 4
2 exists 2
3 exists 1
0 exists 1
4 exists 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string like in your example start by splitting it according to your delimiter ; then you can use a GroupBy Linq query :

```
Dim source = "3,2,3".Split(","c)

Dim query = From item In source
            Group By item Into Count()

For Each result In query
    Console.WriteLine (result)
Next

' output
' { item = 3, Count = 2 }
' { item = 2, Count = 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    Dim a As String = "3,2,3"

    Dim counts As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    For Each value As String In a.Split(",")
        If Not counts.ContainsKey(value) Then
            counts.Add(value, 1)
        Else
            counts.Item(value) = counts.Item(value) + 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In counts
        Debug.Print("Value: " & kvp.Key & ", Count: " & kvp.Value)
    Next
```

Output:

```
Value: 3, Count: 2
Value: 2, Count: 1
```

Comment: I like you answer better, assuming the string represents the data and there will be commas between the numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim count2 as integer = 0
Dim count3 as integer = 0    
For Each c As Char in a
 if c = "3"
      count3 += 1
 else if c = "2"
      count2 += 1
 end if
Next
console.writeline(count2)
console.writeline(count3)
```

I guess, it kinda sounds like homework