# Equivalent of PHP array_count_values in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB.Net because I'm from PHP Development. I would like to ask if there's a function like [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) in VB.NET.

I need to count all occuring items on my excel.

Comment: I don't have a code for this yet. All I have is an array of all data in excel.
I'm doing it PHP but I need to transfer it on VB.Net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Find and count duplicate numbers in a string array in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547427/how-to-find-and-count-duplicate-numbers-in-a-string-array-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With LINQ

```
 Dim myarray As String() = {"HP", "IBM", "HP", "HP", "MICROSOFT"} 

 Dim occur = myarray.GroupBy(Function(f) f).Select( _
                                        Function(f1) New With {.Item = f1.Key, .Count = f1.Count()})

Dim out As String
For Each itm In occur
    out = out & itm.ToString & vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox(out)
```

---

```
{Item = MICROSOFT, Count = 1}
{Item = HP, Count = 3}
{Item = IBM, Count = 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [Array.Length Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx) of the array object.

> Gets the total number of elements in all the dimensions of the Array.

**Example** from MSDN itself:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Declare a single-dimensional string array
        String[] array1d = { "zero", "one", "two", "three" };
        ShowArrayInfo(array1d);
    }

    private static void ShowArrayInfo(Array arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Length of Array:      {0,3}", arr.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Dimensions: {0,3}", arr.Rank)
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
// The example displays the following output:
//       Length of Array:        4
//       Number of Dimensions:   1
```

Comment: care to give me some examples as the examples in the page is complicated sorry.

Comment: @Gorhell:- The example given in MSDN is quite clear and contains the comments, which part you are finding as complex? If you care about only the count then see this part: `Console.WriteLine("Length of Array:      {0,3}", arr.Length);`

Comment: @Gorhell:- I have modified the example for you. Please check and see

Comment: It seems not the one I'm looking for.
Let say i have this array

{HP,IBM,HP,HP,MICROSOFT}

I need an output of

HP = 3
MS = 1
IBM = 1

Comment: @Gorhell:- That is different question to what you asked. Wait I will modify my answer.

Comment: my bad but that's what the function on PHP did

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Dim brands() As String = New String() {"HP", "IBM", "HP", "HP", "MICROSOFT"}
        Dim result = From brand In brands
                     Group brand By brand Into brandgroup = Group

        For Each e In result
            Console.WriteLine("brand : {0} count : {1}", e.brand, e.brandgroup.Count)
        Next
```

Comment: I have a problem with this. cannot beconverted to event args

Comment: replace the e in For Each e with result, and subsequently e.brand and e.brandgroup.Count should be result.brand and result.brandgroup.Count

Comment: Got it. another problem would be excel saving getting from System.Interops {"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"}